# Robot class - If a Button Is Pressed?

Tags: java, mousepress

I have read and understood how the Robot class in java works. Only thing I would like to ask, is how do I press and release the mouse button inside an if statement. For example I would to make a click only if (and right after) the space button is pressed/released. I would use the code:

```
try {
  Robot robot = new Robot();
  if (/*insert my statement here*/) {
    try {
      robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
      robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
  }
} catch (AWTException e) {}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement a key-mouse combination (hold SPACE -> press CLICK), or do you want to have a short window of time (after the key has been pressed) to click the mouse button?

Comment: After the space button is pressed, make a click :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to directly control hardware (well, in fact there **is**, but you would have to use JNI/JNA), this means that you can't simply check if a key is pressed.

You can use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to bind the space key to an action, when the spacebar is pressed you set a flag to `true`, when it's released you set that flag to `false`. In order to use this solution, your application has to be a GUI application, this won't work with console applications.

```
Action pressedAction = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        spaceBarPressed = true;
    }
};

Action releasedAction = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        spaceBarPressed = false;
    }
};

oneOfYourComponents.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "pressed");
oneOfYourComponents.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released SPACE"), "released");
oneOfYourComponents.getActionMap().put("pressed", pressedAction);
oneOfYourComponents.getActionMap().put("released", releasedAction);
```

Then, use

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    if (spaceBarPressed) {
        try {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //handle the exception here
        }
    }
} catch (AWTException e) {
    //handle the exception here
}
```

As GGrec wrote, a better way to do it would be to execute your mouse press directly when the keyboard event is fired:

```
Action pressedAction = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //handle the exception here
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Thing is I want this for a video game of mine so it has to be outside GUI :(

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you listen for the keyboard event, and when you receive it, you execute your code without the `if statement`. Add the listener to your canvas, or whatever.

Careful not to recreate the `Robot` class each time.

```
new KeyAdapter() {

     @Override
     public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e) {

           if (e.keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
                 try {
                     robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                     robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                 }

     }

}
```